# Opening a MVC4 EF5 project created in VS 2012 in 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, enums, visual-studio-2012, compatibility

I created a project in the express edition of VS 2012, it was MVC4 using EF5 Model First with enums. I get this error when trying to run the same project now in VS 2010.

**Error 1   Error 5: The element 'Schema' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm' has invalid child element 'EnumType' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm'. List of possible elements expected: 'Using, Association, ComplexType, EntityType, Function, EntityContainer' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm' as well as any element in namespace '##other'.**

It seems VS2010 does not support enums? But I have checked the EF version being used and it is still v5... so I am confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: I read that EF5 has .net 4.5 dependencies. vs 2010 only handles .net 4.0.

Comment: Same for MVC 4, it depends on .net 4.5 so is not compatible with vs2010.

Comment: @tschmit007 ok your 2nd comment is wrong, I am using MVC4 in VS 2010 and its working fine, the only thing not working is Enums which requires .NET 4.5 / VS 2012

Comment: I refer to [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/157717/what-is-dependency-of-asp-net-mvc-on-net-framework-and-how-to-use-it-with-net) May be you are not using specific parts of MVC 4 ?

Comment: @tschmit007 perhaps its like the EF, says 5 on the tin but its something else inside... like 4.4. Maybe the MVC4 is not using its full capability but however it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity framework will reference 4.4 when you're targeting .NET 4.0 with vs 2010.

> The 4.4 comes from the assembly version of EntityFramework.dll when
>   you install EntityFramework 5.0 into a project that targets .NET
>   Framework 4.0. This is merely a side effect of how the runtime loads
>   and binds to assemblies, and in no way reflects the version of the
>   product.

for more information check [**There is no such thing as Entity Framework 4.4**](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com/2012/10/unicorn-myths-debunked-entity-framework.html)

**Compatibility**

> Some features are only available when writing an application that
>   targets .NET 4.5. This includes enum support, spatial data types,
>   table-valued functions and the performance improvements. If you are
>   targeting .NET 4.0 you still get all the bug fixes and other minor
>   improvements.

For more information check [**EF5 Release**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx) under compatibility section.

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Yep, and its not possible (or hacky) to target .NET 4.5 from VS 2010, which means you need 2012 also.